# angular 2 : not able to redirect to home page after successful login

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I have designed login page with angular 2. After successful verification of username/password, My angular app is not re-directing to user-list page.   There is a problem in statement *this.router.navigate([''])*  in *onSubmit()* method of *login.component.ts*. I have Please help. 
My source code is given below

**auth-gaurd.service.ts**

```java
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGaurdService implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router: Router,
    private authService: AuthenticationService) { }

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    /* the following message is not printed in console */
    console.log("AuthGaurdService :: this.authService.isUserLoggedIn() " + this.authService.isUserLoggedIn())
    if (this.authService.isUserLoggedIn())
      return true;

    this.router.navigate(['login']);
    return false;

  }

}
```

**authentication.service.ts**

```java
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor() { }

  login(username : string, password : string) {
    if (username === "abc" && password === "abc@123") {
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', username)
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username')
    /* it is not printing the following message */
    console.log("AuthenticationService :- " + user);
    console.log(!(user === null))
    return !(user === null)
  }

  logOut() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username')
  }
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```java
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserListComponent } from './user-list/user-list.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './logout/logout.component';
import { AuthGaurdService } from './service/auth-gaurd.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: UserListComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService] },
  { path: 'createUser', component: CreateUserComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService]},
  { path: 'editUser', component: EditUserComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService]},
  { path: 'viewUser', component: ViewUserComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService]},
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'logout', component: LogoutComponent,canActivate:[AuthGaurdService] },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 
  constructor()  {console.log("inside AppRoutingModule") } 
}
```

**login.component.html**

```java
<h2>Login</h2>
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="username" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.username.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.username.errors.required">Username is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.password.errors }" />
        <div *ngIf="submitted && f.password.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
            <div *ngIf="f.password.errors.required">Password is required</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
        <a routerLink="/register" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

**login.component.ts**

```java
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../service/authentication.service';
import { AlertService } from '../service/alert.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  loginForm: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  returnUrl: string;
  invalidLogin = false

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private alertService: AlertService
) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.loginForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          username: ['', Validators.required],
          password: ['', Validators.required]
      });

  }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        console.log("inside login submit")
        // stop here if form is invalid
        if (this.loginForm.invalid) {
            return;
        }

        this.loading = true;
        if(this.authenticationService.login(this.f.username.value, this.f.password.value))
        {
          /*Following message is displayed in console after login success
            However, angular app is not re-directing to user-list page.*/       
          console.log("inside login success")
          this.router.navigate([''])
          this.invalidLogin = false
        } else{
          console.log("inside login false")
          this.invalidLogin = true
        }

      }

}
```

**authentication.service.ts**

```java
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthenticationService {

  constructor() { }

  login(username : string, password : string) {
    if (username === "abc" && password === "abc@123") {
      sessionStorage.setItem('username', username)
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  isUserLoggedIn() {
    let user = sessionStorage.getItem('username')
    console.log(!(user === null))
    return !(user === null)
  }

  logOut() {
    sessionStorage.removeItem('username')
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldnt it be `this.router.navigate(['/'])`

Comment: In my opinion this.router.navigate(['']) is ok. Could you share code for AuthGaurdService? I guess it may return false for this case

Comment: @Przemek- as requested, I have shared code for AuthGaurdService [auth-guard.service.ts]

Comment: @AnindyaKar    ok great, could you check now what is displaying by console.log(!(user === null)) which you have implemented in isUserLoggedIn() or just debug canActivate() function in AuthGaurdService? Btw. you have misspelling in AuthGaurdService.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Przemek!! 
However, it is not going  *authentication.service.ts* and *auth-gaurd.service.ts* as logs are not printing. 
It has printed only logs inside onSubmit() of  *login.component.ts*. Please refer to the attached image.

Comment: @AnindyaKar    It seems like a problem with navigation, but could you just try to remove canActivate for this route and check what will happen? Did you try to navigate to other routes from this place? What version of Angular are you using? Finally, we can analyze logs for navigation, just please add {enableTracing: true} to your routes and check console after click on submit button
ref: https://github.com/delprzemo/angular-cheatsheet#routing